# Issue React-Native Android: Provider permission denial exception

Tags: android, react-native

I am using a react module, react-native-image-picker (https://github.com/marcshilling/react-native-image-picker) to pick the video and get the video URI. Then using module react-native-video, (https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-video) to play the selected URI. But its not working. Using adb logcat, I found that its giving me following error

> Permission Denial: opening provider
>   com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider.MediaContentProvider
>   from (null) (pid=30885, uid=1013) that is not exported from uid 10077

Please tell me how to fix this issue? This is working perfectly on iOS but just giving me hard time on android.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's related to permissions. Check if you configured `react-native-image-picker` properly and also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082708/java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-opening-provider-com-google-andr).

Comment: react-native-image picker is properly configured as I am using it for picking image and its working on android.
I will try the solution suggested in link and see if that resolves it.

Comment: Thanks @Radek for your reply. I am still not able to resolve the issue. As both are third party modules, how to pass URI  received from one module to other module in android without creating permission denial exception?

Comment: Did you find out a solution for this?

Comment: Did anyone find a solution for this ? Kindly, post here, if you did. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found that problem is in react-native-image-picker library. They are not supporting video properly. Currently it doesn't convert content:// URI into file:// URI for videos but they do it for images.