# Java android security exception

Tags: java, android

In my app the user has the ability to take a photo or add a photo to the app.
I'm getting crash reports of java.lang.SecurityException when the app tries to display the saved image in a ImageView

The line it errors on is

```
holder.imageV.setImageURI(uriParsed);
```

I've been unable to duplicate the error myself on either my device or on simulators, they all display the image fine.

The full code I'm using is

```
JoinProjectPicture projectPicture = mProjects.get(position);
Project current = projectPicture.getProject();
Picture picture = projectPicture.getPicture();

 holder.projectName.setText(current.getProjectName() + "(" + current.getWidth() + "x" + current.getHeight() + ")");
 holder.projectStatusTV.setText(current.getStatus());

 if(picture != null) {
      String pictureName = picture.getPictureName();
      Uri uriParsed = Uri.parse(pictureName);

      if(uriParsed != null) {
           Log.d("URIParsed", "Project: " + current.getProjectName() + " - Parsed: " + uriParsed);
           holder.imageV.setImageURI(uriParsed);
    }
}
```

The output from the logs showing on my device ( 3 projects, one without an image)

> Project: Test - Parsed: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.desbrina.diamondpaintinglogbook/files/Pictures/20191111_1408166491573472523237896.jpg
>
> Project: Test 3 - Parsed: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A1891

The error

```
java.lang.SecurityException: 
  at android.os.Parcel.createException (Parcel.java:1966)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1934)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1884)
  at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getContentProvider (IActivityManager.java:4039)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider (ActivityThread.java:6365)
  at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider (ContextImpl.java:2825)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider (ContentResolver.java:1835)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor (ContentResolver.java:1449)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor (ContentResolver.java:1302)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor (ContentResolver.java:1225)
  at android.graphics.ImageDecoder$ContentResolverSource.createImageDecoder (ImageDecoder.java:273)
  at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.decodeDrawableImpl (ImageDecoder.java:1652)
  at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.decodeDrawable (ImageDecoder.java:1645)
  at android.widget.ImageView.getDrawableFromUri (ImageView.java:952)
  at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri (ImageView.java:921)
  at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI (ImageView.java:532)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageURI (AppCompatImageView.java:116)
  at com.desbrina.diamondpaintinglogbook.ui.main.Adapters.ProjectListAdapter.onBindViewHolder (ProjectListAdapter.java:88)
  at com.desbrina.diamondpaintinglogbook.ui.main.Adapters.ProjectListAdapter.onBindViewHolder (ProjectListAdapter.java:23)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder (RecyclerView.java:6781)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder (RecyclerView.java:6823)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline (RecyclerView.java:5752)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline (RecyclerView.java:6019)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition (RecyclerView.java:5858)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition (RecyclerView.java:5854)
  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next (LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk (LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill (LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren (LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2 (RecyclerView.java:3924)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout (RecyclerView.java:3641)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout (RecyclerView.java:4194)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:22406)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6594)
  at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout (ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:22406)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6594)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout (ViewPager.java:1775)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:22406)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6594)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1812)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1656)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1565)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:22406)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6594)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:323)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:261)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:22406)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6594)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1812)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1656)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1565)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:22406)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6594)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:323)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:261)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:22406)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6594)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1812)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1656)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1565)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:22406)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6594)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:323)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:261)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout (DecorView.java:1088)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:22406)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6594)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout (ViewRootImpl.java:3417)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2884)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1932)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:8589)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:949)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:761)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:696)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:935)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7094)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:975)
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: 
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getContentProviderImpl (ActivityManagerService.java:15677)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getContentProviderImpl (ActivityManagerService.java:15586)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getContentProvider (ActivityManagerService.java:16151)
  at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact$getContentProvider$ (IActivityManager.java:11035)
  at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact (IActivityManager.java:295)
```

Comment: Have you tried to build, an obfuscated, release version of your app and test? Does it work?

Comment: can you post full error log. Are you using uri from your phone storage?

Comment: IT will be from either the phone storage, or from within the app, depending on if it was added from the gallery or taken form the camera in app. Full crash added

Comment: Check that the following are satisfied: Write permissions, and that you have a file provider if you are saving to a custom internal path.

Comment: You are saying that you tried the code on emulators. I'd recommend to test such hardware related code on nearly every Android Version. Have you tried it on Android Pie, like the answers below suggest?

Comment: You're probably trying to access data from a third party app.

Comment: I’m trying to access from the photos app

Comment: Look at here may be it would help you https://medium.com/@egemenhamutcu/fixing-securityexception-requiring-a-valid-contentprovider-on-android-8-1110d840522

Answer (score 4):

I think you are getting the Security exception on an Android Pie or later operating system. This is because on these systems you have to declare the path that your app wants to use.

Please check: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider

Additionally, it is possible that your app is trying to get content from another app that requires permission like Google Photos requires: `<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.apps.photos.permission.GOOGLE_PHOTOS"/>`

Check this: [java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.apps.photos.content.GooglePhotosImageProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082708/java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-opening-provider-com-google-andr?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I’m getting it on 9, but I’m running 10 and can’t reproduce it myself. I’ve tried to reproduce it on a 9 similarly or and couldn’t

Comment: I get this error when trying to fire an intent to third-party(it was google photos in my case) gallery app to let choose a photo for my app. So probably you also need an app that needs permission before giving an intent to it.

Comment: I've added that and it still crashes

Answer (score 4):

From Api `24`, you can not access the File Uris directly. You need to use File authorities for the folder and then use

```
val photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", File(path));
```

In **AndroidManifes.xml**

Add the following to `application` tag. In following packagename is `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID`

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="packagename.provider"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

**provider_paths.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Answer (score 3):

This Exception usually is caused by using imageuri from third party app.Solution is to implement file provider.You can get many solution on how to implement fileprovider.

Comment: I've looking and not really sure what I need to change. Currently I'm adding the images using https://pastebin.com/Xswi7puK and showing them with https://pastebin.com/EQVvyRnG

Comment: No, its still crashing

Comment: I tried setting imageUri in an imageview but it works fine for me. The alternative solution is to create a bitmap from the imageuri and set it to imageview.

I think there is a problem in imageuri.where are you getting it from?

Comment: I get the same error trying with a bitmap. The images are being added using the code here. https://pastebin.com/Xswi7puK

Comment: For the 1st case in onActivityResult photoUri is not assigned.

Comment: One the first case it’s set on the menu click

Answer (score 2):

**This is because** at the new version `Android 9` introduced a new `FOREGROUND_SERVICE` permission; the docs say:

> Note: Apps that target `Android 9 (API level 28)` or higher and use foreground services must request the `FOREGROUND_SERVICE permission`. This is a normal permission, so the system automatically grants it to the requesting app.
>   If an app that targets `API level 28` or higher attempts to create a foreground service without requesting `FOREGROUND_SERVICE`, the system throws a `SecurityException`.

Just add the permission to the manifest and should do the trick, "in theory". Let us know!!
Something like:

```xml
<manifest ...>   
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" /> 
     <application ...>
</manifest>
```

Let´s try to take that bounty:
Do you hace these permission?:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Also I think this is not too bad to try:

```java
public static final String KITKAT_VALUE = 1002;

  Intent intent;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19){
                            intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                            intent.setType("image/*");
                            startActivityForResult(intent, KITKAT_VALUE);
                        } else {
                            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                            intent.setType("image/*");
                            startActivityForResult(intent, KITKAT_VALUE);
                    }

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (requestCode == KITKAT_VALUE ) {
     if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
       // do something here
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I’ve had a quick look at the information and not sure how it applies

Comment: Don´t you have a file called `AndroidManifest.xml` where you place all the permissions like : `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
</manifest> `

Comment: I've added that and it still crashes

Comment: Are you using a third app service??? maybe that 3th is using some permissions that are not able to use?

Comment: The 3rd party app it accesses is the phones photo app. The only thing I can think of is I changed the way it accessed it a while ago and I'm wondering if the permissions were never set to keep access. Newly added images from photos work, but it appears older ones don't. This is how the images are added: https://pastebin.com/5CcqXQQu

Comment: Check my answer and hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is down to the permissions you've implemented in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.
If you are debugging on `API Level 23` or higher version of android then you have to take the runtime permission for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` at runtime as Security exception occurs due to permission denied by device.

Comment: Both read and write external are already in the manifest file.

Comment: By the way WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE will be deprecated in the next Android version.